# What kind of ARIMA Model is this?

Tags: time-series, arima

I've got the time series $Y_t = 3 + Y_{t-1} + e_t - 0.75e_{t-1}$ and I'm trying to figure out what p,d,q are for the ARIMA(p,d,q) model.

looking at the $e_t - 0.75e_{t-1}$ part I'd like to say there's an MA(1) part, and possibly and AR(1), but I'm not sure because when I difference the series (since it's not stationary) I get $$ Y_t - Y_{t-1} = 3 
 + e_t - 0.75e_{t-1}$$ which makes me think it's an ARIMA(0,1,1) but I'm not sure how I should be thinking about this. My other guess is an ARIMA(1,1,1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can certainly call it an ARMA(1,1) model with a nonzero mean.

However, as you write, it's nonstationary, and an AR(1) coefficient that is *exactly* 1 is a very... specific parameter value. Which in turn naturally suggests your difference formulation, which is a (now stationary) ARIMA(0,1,1) process with a nonzero mean. I think this is the best way to think about it.

(And of course, any ARIMA(0,1,1) process is also an ARIMA(1,1,1) process, just with the AR(1) parameter equal to zero. Which again is not a very enlightening way of thinking about it. Just stick with the ARIMA(0,1,1) formulation.)

Answer (score 0):

(0,1,1) with a constant and thetha (the ma parameter) is +.75